# ADF Popup disappear on Filtering data

Tags: weblogic12c, oracle-adf

I have been implementing a popup on button click, however when I want to filter the data, Like in highlighted snap & press ENTER the popup disappear. The issues is on every popup. I am using 12.2.1.4.0 version of Jdeveloper. Please help to get out of this stuck
[image]

Here is the code of my Popup:

```
<af:popup id="prodRol"
                    popupFetchListener="#{ProdPgBean.editPopupFetchFabIns}"
                    contentDelivery="lazyUncached">
            <af:dialog id="d4" dialogListener="#{ProdPgBean.editDialogFabInsp}"
                       title="Fill Fabric Inspection Rolls">
              <af:panelCollection id="pc15" inlineStyle="width:500px; height:470px;">
                <f:facet name="menus"/>
                <f:facet name="toolbar">
                  <af:toolbar id="t33">
                    <af:button text="Select All" id="cb38" partialSubmit="true"
                               actionListener="#{ProdPgBean.SelectAllFabricRollInsp}"/>
                    <af:button text="De Select All" id="cb37" partialSubmit="true"
                               actionListener="#{ProdPgBean.DeSelectAllFabricRollInsp}"/>
                  </af:toolbar>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="statusbar"/>
                <af:table value="#{bindings.ProdFbShrnkRollVO1.collectionModel}"
                          var="row"
                          rows="#{bindings.ProdFbShrnkRollVO1.rangeSize}"
                          emptyText="#{bindings.ProdFbShrnkRollVO1.viewable ? 'No data to display.' : 'Access Denied.'}"
                          fetchSize="#{bindings.ProdFbShrnkRollVO1.rangeSize}"
                          rowBandingInterval="0"
                          filterModel="#{bindings.ProdFbShrnkRollVO1Query.queryDescriptor}"
                          queryListener="#{bindings.ProdFbShrnkRollVO1Query.processQuery}"
                          filterVisible="true" varStatus="vs"
                          selectedRowKeys="#{bindings.ProdFbShrnkRollVO1.collectionModel.selectedRow}"
                          selectionListener="#{bindings.ProdFbShrnkRollVO1.collectionModel.makeCurrent}"
                          rowSelection="single" id="t21"
                          binding="#{ProdPgBean.fabricInspRollTable}" autoHeightRows="-1" inlineStyle="height:400px;"
                          styleClass="AFStretchWidth">
                  <af:column headerText="Select "
                             id="c66" align="center" width="40">
                    <af:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{row.bindings.SelpRol.inputValue}"
                                              label="#{row.bindings.SelpRol.label}"
                                              shortDesc="#{bindings.ProdFbShrnkRollVO1.hints.SelpRol.tooltip}"
                                              id="sbc3"/>
                  </af:column>
                  <af:column sortProperty="RollNo" filterable="true"
                             sortable="true" headerText="Roll No." id="c64"
                             align="center">
                    <af:inputText value="#{row.bindings.RollNo.inputValue}"
                                  label="#{bindings.ProdFbShrnkRollVO1.hints.RollNo.label}"
                                  required="#{bindings.ProdFbShrnkRollVO1.hints.RollNo.mandatory}"
                                  columns="#{bindings.ProdFbShrnkRollVO1.hints.RollNo.displayWidth}"
                                  maximumLength="#{bindings.ProdFbShrnkRollVO1.hints.RollNo.precision}"
                                  shortDesc="#{bindings.ProdFbShrnkRollVO1.hints.RollNo.tooltip}"
                                  id="it40">
                      <f:validator binding="#{row.bindings.RollNo.validator}"/>
                    </af:inputText>
                  </af:column>
                  <af:column headerText="Supplier Roll No"
                             id="c137" align="center" sortProperty="SuppRollNo"
                             sortable="true" filterable="true">
                    <af:outputText value="#{row.SuppRollNo}" id="ot14"/>
              
                </af:table>
              </af:panelCollection>
            </af:dialog>
          </af:popup>
```

Answer (score 1):

set the autoCancel property of the af:popup to disabled. This should prevent the popoup closes automatically.

From your description, it's not clear when the popup should close.

Comment: I have set autoCancel property of the af:popup to disabled but it won't work. The popup should only closed when I press the OK or Cancel on Popup.

Comment: Timo Hahn, Pls help on this.